# How to add energy ball which disappears when touched by player in UDK?

Tags: graphic-effects, udk

I am new to UDK and learning game development. I want to know about how to add a ball to the game world with the following effects/actions:

- Glowing effect
- Physics-like object (just having gravity)
- Particles when touched by player-avatar
- Disappears in 1-2 seconds after touch
- Score updates based on different colors of ball

I know little about this can be done by kismet, cascade and content creation, but do not know where to start. Please tell me the steps for this. I am trying this weekend in depth.

Comment: It sounds like you have a lot of things you need to figure out? Or maybe there's something specific you're having a problem with?

Comment: It seems you're asking for a full game in a single question...

Answer (score 1):

The first four thing you want to achieve can be done pretty easily from within UDK without having to use any UnrealCode. The ball will have to be a UTRigidBody, which can be added from the list of actors in the content browser. You can detect when the player is touching it with Kismet using an OnTouch event created with your UTRigidBody(the ball). Same goes for removing it and the particles, fairly simple through basic Kismet nodes.

If you don't know what any of what I just said means, all the information is gone through step by step in much greater detail than I could here in the [official video tutorials](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/VideoTutorials.html#Unreal%20Engine%203%20Video%20Tutorials). If you're just getting started with Unreal, I suggest you start there.